# Does the app store show iPhone 5 users the smaller screenshots too, and vice versa?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, iphone-5

I'm wondering whether I need to make repeating screenshots for both the regular iPhone size and the iPhone 5 size, or whether it shows both to both users. For example, an iPhone 5 user would see the non-iPhone 5 screenshots, as well as their own.

Answer (score 5):

According to my understanding & experience:

1. You must have regular iPhone screenshot (3.5") to submit an app. It always have been this way and that haven't changed.
2. If you support iPhone 5 screen with your app (meaning you put 4" launch screen image) you **must** upload screenshots for iPhone 5, if you won't do that you would be rejected with "Screenshot unavailable", actually your app won't be reviewed till you do.
3. For now you can create 3.5" screen only apps so you could skip creating the 4" screenshots but it seems that soon it would be over and even updates would request 4" screenshots (according to press).
4. You can add 4" screenshots even if your app doesn't support 4", But it **won't be shown on iPhone 5**. The 3.5" screenshots would be shown instead.

Now for the business:

1. If you have 3.5" support only app and you supply 3.5" screenshots (you must do that) it would shown on iPhone 5 and without stretching off-course (same on older devices), Even if you added 4" screenshots.
2. If the app support iPhone 5 screen, each phone would show the appropriate screenshot you submitted (relative to the phone type), iPhone 5 would show iPhone 5 screenshots (the 4" ones you submitted) and older devices would show the 3.5" screenshots. There is no mix.

My recommendation is to create 4" screenshot whenever you have time for that because soon enough it would be probably a must for an update.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is that if you supply iPhone 5 screenshots, it shows them by default on iPhone 5, and no others. I presume this is the same vice versa.

Answer (score -1):

You can't submit an iPhone 5-capable app without iPhone 5 screenshots, so the question is moot. You need to supply screenshots for both device sizes.

Comment: It's not moot at all. I'm asking whether or not iPhone 5 users will see the iPhone 4-sized screenshots, and vice versa. I want to know whether i should re-make all screenshots or not.

Comment: Well, you need at least one, so why not do them all?

Comment: Because I might provide an iPhone 5 screenshot for activity A and keep an iPhone 4 screenshot of the same thing. I now have 2 screenshots the user sees on the app store, or just one - depending on which way it works.

Answer (score -1):

The App Store don't know if the user have an iPhone 4 or an iPhone 5...
So, your App profile on the App Store will show the screenshots that you submit. If you submit only 3.5" screenshots or only the 4", it will show what you sent.
It's recommended to send all screenshots that your App is compatible...