# Bigger launch image on the 5th generation devices

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to develop or migrate apps for iPhone 5 screen resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution)
>   [How to deal with iPhone 5 screen size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396545/how-to-deal-with-iphone-5-screen-size)

With 5th generation devices in the market having bigger screen, we need to have a bigger launch image (image that is shown when app icon is tapped). How would app make the difference like when to use the normal image and when to use the bigger image based on the device type?

I see a warning in my project when I build it for iPhone 6.0 simulator tap on which throws the below alert:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to deal with iPhone 5 screen size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396545/how-to-deal-with-iphone-5-screen-size) and [Develop or migrate apps for iPhone 5 screen resolution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a launch image named **Default-568h@2x.png**. The compiler checks for this image and validates it. If the image is validated, your app is ready for iPhone 5 - otherwise not. Once you have the right image,  follow the steps outlined in this post:

[How to develop or migrate apps for iPhone 5 screen resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution)

If you are having issues with the images being used INSIDE the app, and you want to support iPhone 5 and pre-iPhone 5 devices, use this:

[Dealing with different size images in a xib for iPhone5 versus iPhone4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12753718/dealing-with-different-size-images-in-a-xib-for-iphone5-versus-iphone4/12754158#12754158)

Answer (score 0):

For short: If you want to support iPhone 5 screen you must supply launch screen for the 4" screen otherwise your app would run on 3.5" on the 4" screen. 
If you put the 4" launch image that one would be used on iPhone 5 and the 3.5" one on iPhone 4 (could be different).

Please see my detailed explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12751863/does-the-app-store-show-iphone-5-users-the-smaller-screenshots-too-and-vice-ver/12759663#12759663).